# Why does my while loop keep printing lines?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to create a game like Hangman. A segment of my code asks for a while loop, which is basically supposed to iterate through letter guesses that the player makes.

```
            while len(wordLetters) > 0 and lives > 0:
        print(f'So far, you have guessed these letters: {usedLetters}')
        wordDisplay = [letter if letter in usedLetters else '-' for letter in word]
        print('Current word:', ' '.join(wordDisplay))
        print(visual_hangman[lives])
        if userInput in alphabet - usedLetters:
            usedLetters.add(userInput)
            if userInput in wordLetters:
                print('Correct!')
                wordLetters.remove(userInput)
            else:
                lives = lives - 1
                print(f'Sorry, that is incorrect. You now have {lives} guesses left.')

        elif userInput in usedLetters:
            print('You have already guessed this letter!')

        else:
            print('Invalid character! Please try again.')
```

Basically, this is the while loop that is used to manage the letter guesses, however, when I run it, after guessing one singular letter, the messages printed keep showing up and I cannot control it. What is happening here, can someone explain in simpler terms? Thanks

The while loop is supposed to print if the letter is significant to the word or not. It's supposed to do this every guess, but the first time I guess a letter it keeps printing the same messages, even though I didn't press a single button.

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Looks like you might need to prompt user for a new letter inside the loop.